# What is the difference between «utènsile» and «utensìle»?

Tags: word-choice, homograph

What is the difference between **utènsile** and **utensìle**? What is their proper usage?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

They are the same word, with two different pronunciations. In fact, the correct spelling is 
*utensile*, without accents.

The pronunciation "utènsile" is the only correct one when utensile is used as an adjective (e.g. "una macchina utensile").

According to Treccani, "utensìle" should be used when referring to the noun ("la scatola degli utensili"), but honestly it seems incorrect to me to *require* this pronunciation as the "utènsile" form is very commonly used as a noun, too.

> Come aggettivo (quasi esclusivamente in coppia con il sostantivo macchina), utensile è parola sdrucciola, cioè con l'accento che cade sulla terz'ultima sillaba: utènsile. Come sostantivo, utensile è parola piana (come edìle): utensìle.

--[source](http://www.treccani.it/magazine/lingua_italiana/domande_e_risposte/grammatica/grammatica_044.html)

See also the word "edile".

Comment: ‘Edile’ is not the same: the pronunciation ‘èdile’ is still widely considered incorrect.

Comment: @egreg not according to the Treccani page above

Comment: In http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/edile1/ we read “comune, ma non corretto, èdile”. And the page you quote doesn't say “èdile” can be used as an adjective, but rather tells this pronunciation is not accepted as correct by Devoto-Oli and Treccani.

Comment: Sklivzz is right, but in the everyday life this difference does not count.

Comment: @Lamberto Basti. It does count, it marks the difference between correct and incorrect pronunciation. No matter how many people say "édile", it is still wrong, as much as "mòllica", "rùbrica" and many others.